# Scheduling cron across multiple hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I am working on a Ruby On Rails project.The users are sent reports based on time intervals requested by them through UI developed using Ruby on Rails.
From the controller,I create cron entries for the request and update the crontab file.
The crontab triggers the script which generates  and mails the report to the user.
The users may also edit time intervals for a report and I make changes in crontab file accordingly. To update/create crontab, I create a replica of the cron 'reportcron.cron' and
use the below command to overwrite existing cron file from controller(report_controller.rb)

system("crontab < reportcron.cron")

The problem is that it would work perfectly in a single host.If multiple hosts are used,duplicate cron entries may be created.
Say user creates a new request through host1, next time he may edit the same request through host2, at this time two cron entries for same request are present in host1 (incorrect/previous cron) and host2 (correct/latest cron). I found rubygem clockwork or rufus-scheduler could solve this problem, but I dont know how it works and I am not sure how two hosts would maintain and run cron jobs.Could anyone explain how two hosts maintain cron? I am newbie to ruby and RoR. Please help.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a more suitable scheduler than cron. For example

https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler

The tasks are serialised to a networked data store, so you can have them go to a single point from multiple hosts. You can then work off the tasks at the specified time individually, or in parallel, without fear that you will have any duplication of task or work.

Adapting an example from the README

```
Resque.enqueue_at(5.days.from_now, SendReport, :user_id => current_user.id)
```